# Border isn't showing up

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website layout and I'm trying to put a border around some text, but when I run the code the border never shows. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I double checked it a few times but I must have missed or forgot something :/ Could someone help me out?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>homepage</title>

<style>
    header, nav, main, aside {
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: black;
    }

    header, footer, nav, main {
        max-width: 100%;
    }

    aside {
        width: 150px;
    }
</style>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <header>
            header
        </header>
        <nav>
            nav
        </nav>
        <aside class="left sidebar">
            left sidebar
        </aside>
        <main>
            main
        </main>
        <aside class="right sidebar">
            right sidebar
        </aside>
        <footer>
            footer
        </footer>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify a border style like this:

`border-style:solid`

Learn more about it here:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-style.asp